# Does the web-routes tag have a reason to exist?

Tags: discussion, tags

The [web-routes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-routes?sort=newest) tag is used in a handful of questions about the most diverse technologies (ASP.NET, jQuery, Haskell).

It seems too broad to me. Should it be removed? Am I missing something about it?

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be [*a thing*](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/web-routes) connected to Haskell; however, only two haskell questions are currently so-tagged. Beyond that, it appears to be a synonym of [routes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/routes), and I recommend just merging the two tags.

Comment: I re-tagged as you suggested.